# JQuery Repeatable Field CSS List Last Button Hidden

Tags: jquery, css, field

This is more of a CSS question than a JQuery question, but it includes both.

I am trying to add a a repeatable field to a form... so far everything works out fine except for my CSS...

The HTML for the repeatable field:

```
    <a class="repeatable-add top-link tooltip-link" href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Add a new Address Field">
        <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="controls" id="GMAddresses">
        <ul id="GMAddress-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable" style="list-style:none;margin-left:0;">
            <li>
                <div class="input-prepend input-append" style="margin-left:1%;margin-top:2%;">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-home"></i> <a class="repeatable-up" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a></span>
                    <input type="text" name="GMAddress[0]" style="width:85%;" placeholder="Address Here" required>
                    <span class="add-on"><a class="repeatable-down" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a> <a class="repeatable-remove" href="#"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></a></span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The JQuery for the Repeatable Add button:

```
    //Repeatable Add Button
    $('.repeatable-add').click(function() {
        //Check if there is any open address fields
        var e_error = new Boolean;
        e_error = false;
        $('ul.custom_repeatable').each(function() {
            $(this).find('li').each(function() {
                var mytext = "";
                mytext = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();
                if(mytext === "") {
                    e_error = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
        //Check if the max (7) number of addresses has been reached
        if($('ul.custom_repeatable li').length < 7) {
            if(e_error === false) {
                //Add the extra field if there are no errors
                field = $(this).closest('div').find('.custom_repeatable li:last').clone(true);
                fieldLocation = $(this).closest('div').find('.custom_repeatable li:last');
                $('input', field).val('').attr('name', function(index, name) {
                    return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
                        return Number(n) + 1;
                    });
                })
                field.insertAfter(fieldLocation, $(this).closest('div')).hide().show('slow');
                $('ul.custom_repeatable li:last input').focus();
                return false;
            } else {
                //Show popup if there was an open address field
                $('#extra_address_error2').popover('show');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#extra_address_error2').popover('hide');
                }, 5000);
                $('ul.custom_repeatable li:last input').focus();
            }
        } else {
            //Show popup if max (7) number of addresses has been reached
            $('#extra_address_error1').popover('show');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#extra_address_error1').popover('hide');
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
```

Ok so this works fine except for the repeatable up and down buttons... These button allows the user to move the fields up and down as required however the up button should not be displayed on the first field and the down button should not be displayed on the last field...

This is the CSS I used:

```
    ul.custom_repeatable > li:first-child .repeatable-up {
        visibility: hidden;
        clear:both;
    }
    ul.custom_repeatable > li:last-child .repeatable-down {
        visibility: hidden;
        clear:both;
    }
```

The CSS works fine until I add a new field via the Add Button... Then the Repeatable Down button does not show on the new field...

If i refresh/reorder the fields with JQuery then the CSS works for both buttons...

Please help...

Thanks!

Comment: `.insertAfter()` only takes one argument, what's your second argument for?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The new field is the last field, so it shouldn't display the Down button.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I missed that one... I removed it as it is useless.

Comment: Adding 1 new field I would expect the down button not to show... that is correct however adding another field then the second field still does not have a down button...

Comment: Have you checked the DOM in Firebug or Developer Tools to verify that the structure of the new fields is correct?

Comment: Looks fine... I created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/7xMT4/

Comment: The fiddle works correctly for me in Chrome 26.

Comment: I'm also running chrome 26: Version 26.0.1410.43 m??

Comment: I spoke to soon. It works correctly when I use the Add button, but when I use the Up and Down buttons it doesn't work consistently.

Comment: That's just weird... Did you add 2 fields?

Comment: The buttons work fine one my side... it's just the display that's not working

Comment: I think it may be a browser bug. As I was moving my mouse around in the Elements tab, suddenly the missindg up-arrow appeared.

Comment: Maybe a webkit bug. The glitch happens in Safari as well, but I couldn't get it to happen in Firefox. It seems to be random, or at least I can't figure out the pattern.

Comment: Wanted to say the same thing just now... However Safari (V. 5.1.7) works fine with me... Also tested it in IE and Opera and it works fine there... So it's Chrome that's the issue...